# MSBuild batched output parameters

Tags: batch-file, msbuild

I call NUnit in a batch like this:

```
<MSBuild.ExtensionPack.CodeQuality.NUnit
            ToolPath="$(NUnitToolPath)"
            Assemblies="%(TestOutputFiles.FullPath)"
            ContinueOnError="True"
            Use32Bit="True"
            OutputXmlFile="$(LogDirectory)%(TestOutputFiles.Filename).$(ActiveConfigurationName).xml">          
    <Output TaskParameter="Failures" PropertyName="$(ResultFailures)"/>
    <Output TaskParameter="Errors" PropertyName="$(ResultErrors)"/>
</MSBuild.ExtensionPack.CodeQuality.NUnit>
```

For each Assembly in TestOutputFiles.FullPath NUnit is called and produces the OutputXmlFile, however, I want to create a summary about how many test cases have failed in ALL assemblies at the end.

So I use ContinueOnError und save the Tasks' output parameters. However, I only managed to save them into properties, which are of course overwritten every time the task is called (it's a batch...)

Do you know how to save them into some kind of array? An item group maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change PropertyName attribute for ItemName

```
<Output TaskParameter="Failures" ItemName="ResultFailures"/>
<Output TaskParameter="Errors" ItemName="ResultErrors"/>
```

Keep in mind that ItemName and PropertyName are mutually exclusive. You cant specify both